# После долгого импортирования в БД (в чистую базу успешно заливаются более 4700 записей), возникает ошибка KeyError: 'address'

Tags: python, django

Помогите пожалуйста (кто чем может) решить проблему.
Парсю данные и заливаю их в БД.

```
### часть кода из 1го метода, который завершается формированием словаря
basic_dict[self.country][city.text.lstrip()][name] = dict(
    detailed_url=detailed_url,
    place_type=self.place_type
)

### тут 2ой метод, который завершается расширением первого словаря
extended_dict[self.country][city][cinema].update(dict(
    address=street1,
    phone_number=phone1,
    official_website=website1)
)
self.showtime(extended_dict)

### тут 3ий метод, который принимает расширенный словарь 
###   и начинает уже парсить данные и заливать в БД.
def showtime(self, extended_dict):
    showtime_dict = extended_dict

    for city in showtime_dict[self.country]:
        for cinema in showtime_dict[self.country][city]:
            url = showtime_dict[self.country][city][cinema]['detailed_url']
            showtimes_tab_url = '/showtimes/#!=&cinema-section=%2Fshowtimes%2F'
            tree = prepare_content(url + showtimes_tab_url)

            for film in tree.xpath('//div[@class="content"]'):
                film_name = film.xpath('.//a[@class="navi"]/text()')[0]
                for date in film.xpath('.//li[contains(@class,"showtimes-day sdt")]'):
                    film_date = date.xpath('.//div[@class="date"]/text()')[0]

                    for time in date.xpath('.//ul[@class="showtimes-day-block"]/li'):
                        film_time = time.xpath('string(a/text())')
                        film_buy_ticket_url = time.xpath('string(a/@href)')

                        if len(film_time) == 0:
                            film_time = None
                        is_3d = time.find('span')
                        film_format = ''

                        if film_time is not None:
                            if is_3d is not None:
                                film_format = '3D'
                            else:
                                film_format = '2D'

                            # IMPORT
                            from app_places.models import Place
                            from app_shows_and_times.models import Show, Showtime

                            get_showtime_place = Place.objects.get(
                                 place_name=cinema, 
                                 place_street=showtime_dict[self.country][city][cinema]['address']
                            )
                            get_showtime_show = Show.objects.get(show_name = film_name)

                            showtime = Showtime.objects.create(
                                showtime_dates=film_date,
                                showtime_times=film_time,
                                showtime_format=film_format,
                                showtime_buy_ticket_url=film_buy_ticket_url,
                                showtime_place=get_showtime_place,
                                showtime_show=get_showtime_show
                            )
```

Часть модели (и так уже кода много), где можно увидеть, что 2 поля идут как уникальные.

```
class Place(models.Model):
    place_name = models.CharField(max_length = 50, db_index = True)
    place_street = models.CharField(max_length = 80)
    place_phone = models.CharField(max_length = 60)
    place_official_site = models.URLField(max_length = 255, blank = True)
    place_country = models.ForeignKey(Country)
    place_city = models.ForeignKey(City)
    place_type = models.ForeignKey(PlaceType)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'place'
        unique_together = (('place_name', 'place_street'))
```

.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/antonio/projects/idemvdvoem.com/idemvdvoem.com/src/shared/parser_to_db.py", line 23, in __init__
    self.basic_cinemas_info()
  File "/home/antonio/projects/idemvdvoem.com/idemvdvoem.com/src/shared/parser_to_db.py", line 176, in basic_cinemas_info
    self.detailed_cinemas_info(basic_dict)
  File "/home/antonio/projects/idemvdvoem.com/idemvdvoem.com/src/shared/parser_to_db.py", line 225, in detailed_cinemas_info
    self.showtime(extended_dict)
  File "/home/antonio/projects/idemvdvoem.com/idemvdvoem.com/src/shared/parser_to_db.py", line 271, in showtime
    get_showtime_place = Place.objects.get(place_name = cinema, place_street = showtime_dict[self.country][city][cinema]['address'])
KeyError: 'address'
```

Проблема. Запускаю класс, пошел импорт, который заканчивается KeyError: ‘address’, при том что 4700 записей в БД уже создано (базу предварительно очищаю), значит, как я понимаю, до какого-то этапа данное выражение:

```
get_showtime_place = Place.objects.get(place_name = cinema, place_street = showtime_dict)
```

работает. Но никак не могу понять, откуда возникает сбой.

Соответственно 3 вопроса:

1) Правильно ли я использую `unique`? Т.е. в модели задал в мета классе, а в `objects.get` указываю оба эти поля. Так и нужно?

2) Нужно ли для `place_street = models.CharField(max_length = 80)` делать `db_index = True`?

3) По какой причине может идти заливка в БД со ссылкой на ‘address’ в словаре, и в итоге выдавать ошибку?
Как одно из предположений, возможно 4700 записи и должно быть, но я тогда не понимаю, почему процесс заканчивается ошибкой.

Простите за кучу кода.

**UPD 1:**
Думал уже, может где-то в базе `Place` нету записи street. Проверил - улицы везде указаны.

**UPD 2:**
Только лег в кровать, пришло озарение, как можно найти проблему.
У меня есть модель Showtimes, которая связана через FK с Places.

1 кинотеатр с адресом *ул. Лаврухина, 4. ТЦ "РайON"* вообще не проимпортировался в Places.

Подумал, что может скобки. Проверил - `.replace('“', "'").replace('”', "'").replace('"', "'")` - не помогло.
Может проблема в кириллице+латинице в названии?
Может как то unique_together влияет? У меня postgreSQL

Может теперь будет кому-то легче подсказать, куда мне ковырять?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема решена. Оказалось, что при парсинге для одного кинотеатра не оказалось информации об официальном веб-сайте. Так как я проверку полей не делал, то в словарь не добавлялись данные cinema_street, cinema_phone, cinema_website для этого одного кинотеатра. Нету данных -> ошибка.

Мой код без проверки наличия данных на сайте.

```
for city in extended_dict[country]:
    for cinema in extended_dict[country][city]:
        url = extended_dict[country][city][cinema]['detailed_url']
        tree = prepare(url)

        for street in tree.xpath(".//div[@class='address']"):
            cinema_street = street.xpath("text()")[0].strip()

            for phone in tree.xpath(".//div[@class='phone']"):
                cinema_phone = phone.xpath("text()")[0].replace('Телефон:', '').strip()

                for website in tree.xpath(".//div[@class='website']/a"):
                    cinema_website = website.xpath("@href")[0].strip()

                    extended_dict[country][city][cinema].update(dict(address = cinema_street,
                                                                    phone_number = cinema_phone,
                                                                    official_website = cinema_website))
```